# High Scheduling Metrics Wait Time in cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to collect some performance numbers using cosmos db. With current test runs I am getting higher latency for each query.

After analyzing QueryMetrics for each query I got to know that, each query spending less time in 'Total Query Execution Time' and more time in 'Scheduling Metrics Wait Time (ms)'.

> Total Query Execution Time : 0.62 milliseconds
>
> Scheduling MetricsWait Time (ms) : 11.31

What can be possible reason behind high 'Scheduling Metrics Wait Time (ms)'? What are possible solutions to reduce wait time?

```
        var getDoc= "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = /"5/"";
        FeedOptions feedOptionsUsers = new FeedOptions
        {
            PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
        };

        IDocumentQuery<dynamic> documentQuery =
            client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, getDoc, feedOptionsUsers).AsDocumentQuery();
```

Comment: Have you already checked this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-query-performance

Comment: Yes I have gone through that doc multiple time but no one talks about wait time I am seen in scheduling.

Comment: What does Scheduling Metrics Wait Time (ms) in Query Metric signifies?

Comment: Scheduling Metrics wait times are typically high if the client machines have high CPU. From what you mention it could be possible that the client machine could have higher CPU since you're running a perf test. What CPU are you hitting during your perf tests on your client?

Comment: Its less than 10% CPU